# How do I create an ActionLink to the Index action of a different controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

How do I change the following code to produce the proper URL?

Note: The ActionLink is being produced from a different controller than DomainsController.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Domains", "Index", "Domains", new { id = item.Name }, null)
```

The goal is to see the following URL.

```
/Domains/ItemName
```

What I'm getting is:

```
/Domains/Index/ItemName
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange routing :)

Here goes quick and dirty solution:

```
@{string link= "Domains/" + item.Name;}
@Html.ActionLink("Domains", "", link, null, null)
```

Comment: What is your suggestion for the proper URL?  /ItemName/Domains?  That makes more sense, but I'm not sure how to implement that either.  The goal is to have a user-friendly URL that displays the domains associated with a specific item.

Comment: It depends on your structure, security requirements... I would look into options with routing to find an elegant solution, here is the link with MVC resources, and has section with routing articles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416514(VS.98).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is little impractical. You certainly *can* achieve that with something like

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
                "Domains/{id}",
                new { controller = "Domains", action = "Index" }
);
```

But then, you would have to create explicit routing rules for all of the other `DomainsController` action methods, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use simply e.g. `/Domains/OtherAction` anymore - it would be caught by the aforementioned rule and interpreted as a call to the `Index` method with `id == "OtherAction"`